# Lost birth certificate

Tags: florida, birth-certificate

I lost my birth certificate during Hurrican IAN in Fl and need a replacement what are the steps to get it? My home was destroyed and became uninhabitable and therefore I lost all my Identifications. CN I request for this online and if so how do I prove who I am without other ID?

Comment: Here is where and how: https://www.floridahealth.gov/certificates/certificates/birth/index.html

Comment: A propos the proof without ID question, you will eventually have to swear under penalty of perjury that the information you give is correct.

Comment: You may be able to replace a lost Florida driver license or ID card on line, or at an office, based on the information they have on file. See [the relevant web page](https://www.flhsmv.gov/driver-licenses-id-cards/renew-or-replace-your-florida-driver-license-or-id-card/).

Comment: Were you born in Florida?  The process of replacing a birth certificate depends on where you were born.